# Changed password in connectionstring not released by DLL

Tags: asp.net, dll, connection-string

We have a DLL project for a web app project in a solution. The DLL has connectionstrings for each distinct connection used by our app, passed in as properties via a method in the DLL. This all works and has been in production for a few years. Recently after a UAT release in which the database was refreshed, we found that the connections defined within the app which reference the password via ASP:SqlDataSource tag in the ConnectionString property still work, whereas the ones called from the DLL all fail. We have recycled the App Pool, and deleted the files in the \bin directory and re-published them, still those connections all fail with "Could not connect to SQL" error thrown.

Has anyone experienced and already fixed this sort of issue? Or have any other ideas to try? Thanks.

Comment: So the password was changed that is used to connect to the database? Where are these DLL properties configured?

Answer (score 0):

We got it sorted. The DBA team had changed the password, but there was another underlying issue within the application which did not present itself in an exception with details that matched the actual problem. We truncated and re-imported our user credentials table and now all methods in the DLL work as expected.

Our methods in the DLL are all internals, and the initialization method populates private static strings for each connection string. It was only one of these that failed, so we knew it wasn't the DLL at fault. Just had to isolate the root cause and remedy it to get passed the initial fear that somehow the DLL did not obtain the new password.